# Push notification display behavior in apple watch

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

I used the dynamic long-look format to display a custom message in the Apple Watch app. But it is strange that:

1. When the remote notification is coming, then it is OK to display the custom message in dynamic look if the user check it in the meantime.
2. But if the user does not read it on time, the unread message will go into notification, next time if the user swipe down to check the unread notification, the message can not display the custom content, seems the notification will display in static look automatically.

My questions are:

1. Is this the expected behavior handled by Apple, or it is because any issue happen then system auto fall back to static look?
2. Is there any way to make unread message to display in dynamic look in notification?